# Updating multiple fields at once

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find all instances of the word true throughout the table and change them to a '1'.  To save time in the future, I'd like to be able to change every column at once and only run one query.

`update myTable
set field1, field2, field3=1
where field1, field2, field3='true'`

that's kinda what i'm looking at doing.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using (eg. mySql/Oracle/etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update mytable
set
field1 = case when field1='true' then 1 else field1 end,
field2 = case when field2='true' then 1 else field2 end,
field3 = case when field3='true' then 1 else field3 end
where 
    field1 ='true' or field2='true' or field3='true'
```

Comment: +1 for catching it early

Comment: @josbo, you probably don't need the where clause

Comment: ok so this is now a duplicate... but .. the where clause will save some unnecessary updates... for rows that don't need updating

Comment: the two lines with "then 2" should be "then 1"

Answer (score 2):

Your current syntax is close.  You need to specify the value for each field:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
   Field1 = CASE WHEN Field1 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE Field1 END,
   Field2 = CASE WHEN Field2 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE Field2 END,
   Field3 = CASE WHEN Field3 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE Field3 END
```

This will check every row and update those fields as needed.

Comment: He didn't say where ALL where true...only to replace each that was true with a '1'

Comment: @Gerrat - good catch, I didn't see that.  I'll update.

Comment: This will NOT work either... if field 2 is 0 already... ie field1 = 'true' and field 2 & 3 are 0 then it will not "FIX" field 1

Comment: You probably want to add `Where Field1 = 'True' OR Field2 = 'True' OR Field3 = 'True'`

Answer (score 1):

no, there isn't a easy way of doing this as you wrote.

what you can do is dynamically loop through the columns using:

```
select name from sys.columns
  where object_id=(
  select object_id from sys.objects where name like 'myTable '
)
```

and check one by one.

It requires some coding and the execution time wouldn't be the best, but it will avoid you of writing a lot of code and, the main advantage, you can change the table by just changing the name.